# Change css properties of 3 divs on scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Just wanting to find out if this is possible before I try hacking together some code.

I have a site built on the twitter bootstrap with a fixed-nav at the top.

In the nav I have an image with .css property set of height and width, and a margin set on the navbar itself of 155px, and then body padding of 180px to compensate for the big fixed nav. This is followed by a carousel (bootstrap feature).

The question is, is it possible to resize that nav, by changing those 3 css properties of 3 divs as the user scrolls past the carousel. I would like the nav to go from 180px down to 30 px and stay fixed to the top of the page once the user scrolls past the carousel. Just to use up less page real estate. The kicker is I am using the responsive sizing, so this would only affect the people viewing on devices larger than 979px wide. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's possible but it would be better to show the live page. you can see something similar on [this page](http://heera.it/) but not responsive yet but it'll be soon. [Check this too](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need scroll function

here is is demo implement class on menu and style element according to it
http://jsfiddle.net/hushme/3T6LT/2/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
if (sc > 50) {
    $("#menu").addClass('small')
} else {
     $("#menu").removeClass('small')
}
```

});

Comment: This works, however is it possible to animate the resize event. So if they scroll down 50% of the total pixels needed the resize of the bar is only at 50% of its resize

Comment: i dont understand please explain a bit

Answer (score 1):

Try `.scroll` function of jquery

```
$('.yourSelector').scroll(function(){
    //use the css function to change or resize the 3 divs
}));
```

You can have a full reference of jquery http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

and the `.css` function http://api.jquery.com/css/

Hope it helps..

Comment: This works as well, however is there a way to animate the transformation. See http://findandform.com

Comment: instead of using `.css` use `.animate` refer to jquery website for full reference to this function

Answer (score 1):

You can get an idea from this (I wrote it a few days ago as [an article here](http://heera.it/jquery-sticky-menu-plugin))

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.stickyMenu = function( options ) {
        var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            'left' : 0,
            'top' : 0,
            'menu_offset_top' : $this.offset().top
        },
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        $(window).on('scroll.stickyMenu', function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > settings.menu_offset_top)
            {
                $this.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top':settings.left,
                    'left':settings.top,
                    'zIndex':9999
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $this.css({
                    'position': 'relative',
                });
            }
        });
        return $this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is real close to exactly what I am talking about. Can I attach an animate feature or is it either one or the other.

Comment: Sure you can attach an `animate` feature. This is just the base idea and you can expand it.